# Online Hebrew Lexicon for learning Tanakh

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, adult-learning

Shalom, it is my goal to significantly improve my Hebrew this year.
It was recommended to me that an online Hebrew Lexicon, which allows you to analyze each word of Tanakh, including grammar, definition’s, parsing verbs, diagramming verses etc, would be a useful tool.

A online search for such a Lexicon, turned up several options, but they are all Xtian programs. Does such a tool exist for Jewish students of the Hebrew Bible? And if so, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alhatorah.org has one, fantastic site overall.

https://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance

Comment: Thank you, I just reviewed it briefly, seems to have most of the features I’m looking for, once I learn how to use properly ;)

Comment: Update; this is a great tool, thanks again….

Comment: That's great to hear!

Comment: @ Nahum Do you (or anyone else here) know of any other options? (For comparison)

Comment: I do not (15 characters)